# How to update child in Master-Detail relationship with REST API?

Tags: rest-api, relationships, master-detail

I have a Master-Detail relationship with Accounts and Locations.

I am able to create the child using `upsert`, but when I try to update the `Account__c` field I get

```
(INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE: Unable to create/update fields: Account__c. 
Please check the security settings of this field and verify that it is read/write 
for your profile or permission set.)
```

Profile and permission set look OK, from what I can tell.

Using Restforce.

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to reparent a child. Did you check that you are allowed to do so? (check the MD field on the child object)

Comment: @SebastianKessel - Thank you. That was it. Can you create an answer?

Comment: Done. Glad it worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're trying to reparent a child.

Go to the MD field on the child's object and check the box that would allow you to do so.